# Overriding updateDisplayList

Tags: apache-flex, render, displaylist

I'm starting with a Flex project that I'm maintaning, and I'm very curious about something I just tried a couple of minutes ago.

There is this method:

override protected function updateDisplayList

which does something like this:

someLabel.y = someLabel.height + 5;

All good, but when I try to do this:

someLabel.x = someLabel.width + 5;

NOTHING is rendered anymore when I run the project. It does not crash, it's like the renderer stops working.

Any ideas?.

Funny thing, I'm not new to Flex or AS3.. but I never tried to override that method though.

Thanks!.

Comment: Did you check what `someLabel.x` is. Maybe it just got moved off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems like having the "right" property set in the label mxml in addition with the x property in the overridden updateDisplayList is not a good combo, as soon as I removed the left property it worked just fine.

(thanks to ced-b for creating a spark of thought!)